# Incremental Refactoring Toward Null Object: C++ overloading

Tags: c++, design-patterns, null, refactoring, operator-overloading

We've got a large legacy C++/ObjC++ application that could benefit from Null Object to replace thousands of redundant checks:

```
Thing *thing=CurrentSelection();
if (thing) thing->Drill()
```

If, when nothing was selected, CurrentSelection returned an instance of NotAThing

```
class NotAThing public: Thing 
{
public:
    virtual ~NotAThing(){}
    virtual bool IsValid() const { return false;}
    virtual void Drill() {}
};
```

We could get rid of almost all those checks.  For a well contained class with few clients, Null Object can be a Good Thing.  But this class is ubiquitous; dozens of classes depend on it and there are thousands of checks.

Can we incrementally refactor *toward* Null Object?

One approach would be to overload operators on NotAThing to lie:

We'd need to overload !, !=, and probably the casts to bool and int. And that still won't catch the explicit comparison "thing==nil". And I can already hear Scott Meyers (*Effective C++*) warning that this was lies madness.  At minimum, it's a code smell.

And, while we might incrementally back out some of these and lean on the compiler in order to find and remove unneeded nil tests, I worry about coercion chains causing confusing and unexpected results -- one reason to avoid those casts.

On the other hand, there’s all those nil checks. They’re a code smell, too.

What’s the wisdom for large-scale refactoring toward null object?  The mechanics in Fowler and in Kerievsky are sound, but they’re designed for classes with a small number of clients

Comment: Your overloaded op= is irrelevant in the context. There you deal with Thing * that is a pointer, not the object, and uses the built-in operator always.

Comment: Quite right!  Revised to address this, lest others be deceived by my blunder. Sorry!  Can one overload the function operator==(Thing*,void*)?  For the idiomatic coercion if(thing){...}, do we overload the coercion to int or bool or what?  Sigh.